# How to set a dynamic color for a TreeItem icon in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In my Visual Studio Code extension I want to build a tree that displays a class hierarchy. These classes are usually from different namespaces. As a visual aid I want to assign the icon of the tree item in a color from a dynamically generated palette.

The constructor of the `vscode.ThemeColor` class appears to only accept color IDs which are statically defined in `package.json`. Like this:

```
const c = new vscode.ThemeColor('my.color.id');
```

I have looked through the [Theme Color](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color)  and [File Icon](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/file-icon-theme) API reference but I cannot see how to achieve goal.

I tried to dynamically generate SVG data but I failed loading the images into the the item.

I also tried to dynamically alter the color palette configuration but I did not succeed.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: To my knowledge it is not possible with the public API. I wish there was a way to style trees views.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be this way. I am currently trying to define a color palette in package.json and then update these values inn runtime as needed. But since I am a newbie, I am struggling with accessing the values in the configuration.

Comment: Reading package.json is as trivial as reading any other file (use the fs package). But how to color the tree items then is the main problem.

Comment: I am trying to use the .getConfugration('workspace') API which seems to provide access to the colorCustomizations. If I could update these values, I think it would be possible.

Comment: I meant getConfugration('workbench')..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an acceptable solution for my problem. It is possible to dynamically add colors to the workbench configuration like this:

```
const workbench = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration("workbench");

const colorCustomizations: any = workbench.get("colorCustomizations");

workbench.update(
    "colorCustomizations",
    {
        ...colorCustomizations,
        "my.color": "#ff0000",
    },
    1,
);
```

This does not even require a definition in the extension's `package.json` file. Now I can use my custom color like any other:

```
const c = new vscode.ThemeColor('my.color')
```